# Cant create a handle, or handle is invalid - WinAPI (CreateFile)

Tags: winapi, handle, createfile, file-copying

This is a piece of my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <iostream.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <stdarg.h>

    int main(int argc, char * agrv[]) {

        //Convert argument 2 to wide char pointer
        wchar_t w[MAX_PATH];
        size_t size_of_w = sizeof(w);
        mbstowcs_s(&size_of_w, w, argv[1], MAX_PATH);
        LPWSTR pFile = w;

        //Copy original file to temp file
        if (!CopyFile(w, L"temp.out", False))
        {
            printf("Error: could not copy file.");
            printf("CopyFile Errorcode %d\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        pFile = L"temp.out";

        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(pFile, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            printf("Error: could not create handle to file");
            printf("CreateFile Errorcode %d\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Successfully created Handle");
        return 0;
    }
```

Im trying to open a handle for the newly copied file "temp.out", but an error is thrown and it doesnt work.

My debug print (printf(`"CreateFile Errorcode %d\n", GetLastError());`)
prints "CreateFile Errorcode: 2" (File not found) but it is found, becasue CopyFile works just well.

**EDIT:**
I've used absolute path, now, when Im trying to map the file to the memory using the handle, it throws '6', which means invalid handle:

```
    HANDLE pMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,0 ,0 ,NULL);
        LPVOID lpBase MapViewOfFile(pMap, FILE_MAP_ACCESS| FILE_MAP_EXECUTE, 0, 0, 0);
        printf("CreateFileMapping Errorcode %d\n", GetLastError());
        if (!lpBase)
        {
            printf("Error: could not map file to memory");
            printf("CreateFileMapping Errorcode %d\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Successfully mapped file");
```

**EDIT 2:**

Ive added error handling to CopyFile, but it works OK and DOES copy the file.
the output is now:

> program.exe shit.txt
>   Successfully created Handle
>   Error: could not map file to memory
>   createMapFile errorcode: 6

Comment: the directory has to exist

Comment: what do you mean, It does exist... Im running it within a directory that has a file in it and it copies the file and names it temp.out @paulm

Comment: Try using absolute file paths.

Comment: You are calling `GetLastError` at the wrong time. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) specifically notes to call `GetLastError`, if the function fails. You are calling it unconditionally.

Comment: I wonder why seemingly so many people make this basic mistake.

Comment: Yes, the error handling is off. Try to fix that up and edit the question to include code with correct error handling. Do check for errors on all api calls.

Comment: @Jonathan It is frustrating. Especially when askers often don't seem to care when you point this out. I suspect many of them remove the error checking code after having debugged it, believing that the errors won't happen anymore!

Comment: I did not understand. how can I handle the error if not like that? where should I use `GetLastError`?

Comment: @johnnybravo Unless `CreateFile` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` you don't have an error to handle.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Ok, but on the next function (EDIT), the handle turns out invalid.. why is this happening?

Comment: On the next function you're doing the same thing (and actually that code won't even compile as shown). *DON'T CALL GETLASTERROR() UNLESS SOMETHING FAILS*.

Comment: I realized my mistake with GetLastError.. Such a dumb one

Comment: although I did what you said and called GetLastError only after the error occured (inside the if) and its the same error again, (when trying to map the file) 6.

Comment: Dude... you are calling `GetLastError` before checking for an error condition. Can this really be **this** hard to understand?

Comment: @IInspectable I changed that in my code.. Now I edited that here as well..

Comment: You also need to call `GetLastError` immediately, and save away the answer. What if the call to `printf` clears the error? And you don't check `CopyFile` for errors. Please fix your error handling.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan can printf make an "invalid handle" error?! also, I chaged the code and added edits.

Comment: This is a classic example of the asker that doesn't want to learn. You have bigger problems than the specifics of this question. You don't understand Win32 error handling and you don't seem to want to learn. Why not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that isnt true.. Do I need to learn win32 error handling? fine.

Comment: Yes you do need to learn error handling. It's absolutely critical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `<iostream.h>`, consider using a new compiler!

You can use `wmain` to avoid string conversion. Although you don't really need that, and you don't need to create a file. Use `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` instead of `hFile`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    const int buflen = 1000;
    wchar_t* mapName = L"MyMapName";
    wchar_t* message = L"123\0";

    HANDLE hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, buflen, mapName);
    if (!hFileMapping)
    {
        printf("CreateFileMapping error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    LPVOID buf = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, buflen);
    if (!buf)
    {
        printf("MapViewOfFile error %d\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        return 1;
    }
    CopyMemory(buf, message, (wcslen(message) * sizeof(wchar_t)));
    system("pause");//wait until another program reads this data
    UnmapViewOfFile(buf);
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
    return 0;
}
```

If you use a real file handle instead of `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` then use this method instead (note, `buflen` is zero):
`CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, mapName);`

In another program:

```
int wmain()
{
    const int buflen = 1000;
    wchar_t* mapName = L"MyMapName";
    HANDLE hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, mapName);
    if (!hMapFile)
    {
        DWORD e = GetLastError();
        printf("OpenFileMapping %d\n", e);//EDITED: this line was missing
        return 1;
    }

    wchar_t* buf = (wchar_t*)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, buflen);
    if (!pBuf)
    {
        DWORD e = GetLastError();    
        printf("MapViewOfFileerror %d\n", e);//EDITED: this line was missing
        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        return 1;
    }
    wcout << buf << endl;
    UnmapViewOfFile(buf);
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);
    return 0;
}
```